# Is it possible to write on input text and show on label on 2 seconds later?

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a problem I try write on input text and show the text on a label but I want show the text 2 seconds later, example, write on input "save" and 2 seconds later show on the label, "save". I have it right now but I don't know how wait 2 seconds to print it on label.

```
<script>
function show() {



var ingreso1 = document.show__.ingreso1.value;
   try{
       ingreso1 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso1)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso1);
       document.show__.total.value = ingreso1;
   }
   catch(e) {}
}
</script>

<form name="show">
<input type="text" name="ingreso1" onKeyUp="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="total" disabled><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Also, PHP != JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

you could use setTimeout function.

suppose your input id is inTest and label id is lblTest

the code will be:

```js
function handleOnchange(eventArg){
  console.log(eventArg.target.value);
  setTimeout(function(val){ 
  
    document.getElementById('lblTest').value = val;
  
  }, 2000, eventArg.target.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="show">
<input type="text" name="ingreso1" onKeyUp="handleOnchange(event)" id="inTest" /><br><br>
<input type="text" name="total" disabled id="lblTest" /><br>
</form>
```